# Equality of basis pursuit formulations

Tags: linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, lagrange-multiplier, nonlinear-system

Usually I've seen the basis pursuit problem formulated as

$$\min_{x\in R^N}{\left\lVert x\right\rVert}_1 \quad \text{subject to} \; b=Ax$$

but in [this paper](ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam10-41.pdf), they formulate it as

$$\min_{x \in R^N} \mu||x||_1 + \frac{1}{2}||Ax-b||_2^2$$

(with $u=x$ and $f=b$, equation (1) in the paper).

I can't find the reference that proves these two formulations are equal.  Is it based on a general rule similar to a Lagrangian?  Or is there a proof for this specific instance (in which case, please provide a reference).

**Update:**  It looks like this is actually the formulation for [basis pursuit denoising](ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam10-41.pdf).

In the wikipedia article, it says this problem becomes basis pursuit as $\mu \rightarrow \infty$ ($\mu=\lambda$ in their form), but I don't think this is true, as then the constraint term falls off.  Is there a way to find $\mu$ such that the formulations are equal?